# Draw matplotlib plot to PNG in Jupyter when inline matplotlib is enabled

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am drawing a confusion matrix heatmap in Jupyter using code similar to the [example here using imshow](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#example-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py)

Matplotlib is set to draw plots inline.

This works fine for outputting to the cell in the notebook, but I want to *not* output to the cell but instead get PNG data (ideally raw, not saved to a file) *in this case only*, not in general (in general I want matplotlib to display inline).

I'm not quite sure how to do that; examples I've seen seem to be global in nature (e.g. calling matplotlib.use() before importing pyplot).

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to not display the plot inline, is to use `plt.close()` at the end of the cell.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
plt.savefig("image.png")
plt.close()
```

Comment: Well, that's a whole lot simpler!

Answer (score 2):

Turn off interactive mode:

```
plt.ioff()
```

To reactivate inline images, use

```
plt.ion()
%matplotlib inline
```

---

To save the PNG image as bytes, but not to a file, pass a file-like `io.BytesIO` object to `plt.savefig` instead of a file:

```
import io
data = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(data)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is probably the answer I'm looking for even though it won't work for me as I'm running in a container and don't have Tk available, and no other backend seems to work either.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I can use 'pdf' or a few others with `plt.switch_backend`.

Comment: I've revised my answer -- It appears calling `%matplotlib tk` first is unnecessary. Therefore, if the above answer works for you, you should not need to even call `plt.switch_backend`.

Comment: I'll throw in a couple more curve balls - I need to wrap this up in an API callable within my notebook. So calling %matplotlib magic is out. However, is it even necessary? Wouldn't ion/ioff be enough?

Secondly, the original example called imshow which is a top-level function, not a method, so I don't actually have an object to call savefig on. I'm hoping Figure.figimage might work as an alternative. Will report back (I'm new to using matplotlib if that wasn't obvious).

Comment: You do not need to change backends, savefig is smart enough to take care of that for you

Comment: To answer my second question - duh, plt.savefig is itself a top-level function, so I don't need an object reference.

Comment: tcaswell, that isn't true. Without the ion/ioff calls that unutbu suggested the plot will be displayed inline (as well as saved).

Comment: I can replace the magic with `get_ipython().enable_matplotlib('inline')` so I think I'm good. Thanks for all the help.